# Calling method from child classes having same name - java

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, parent

I have a program with 1 parent class and multiple child classes. All child classes have the same method name but doing different functions.I want to be able to call the method from a particular class. For example

```
class A
{
 public void doABC()
  { 
    //do something; 
    //call Class B's method didABC; 
    //call Class C's method didABC }
}

class B extends A
{
  public void didABC()
  {
    //does something;
  }
}

class C extends A
{
  public void didABC()
  {
    //does something;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to call Class B's `didABC` and Class C's `didABC` when I want to. How would I do this?

Comment: If you know exactly which method you want to call, then inheritance is probably the wrong tool for the job. Just move them all to A, and give them different names.

Answer (score 4):

Just create an instance of the child class and call method on it.

To call class B's didABC:

```
B b = new B();
b.didABC();
```

To call class C's didABC:

```
C c = new C();
c.didABC();
```

You can hold the object of child classes in parent class reference and call the methods using that reference also. Whichever class object the parent class will hold it will simply call that class method.

```
A a = new A();
a.didABC(); // class A method will be called
a = new B();
a.didABC(); // class B method will be called
a = new C();
a.didABC(); // class C method will be called
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void doABC() { didABC(); }
    public abstract void didABC();
}

class B extends A
{
    public void didABC() { System.out.println("B::didABC()"); }
}

class C extends A
{
    public void didABC() { System.out.println("C::didABC()"); }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
A b = new B();
b.doABC(); // Prints "B::didABC()"

A c = new C();
c.doABC(); // Prints "C::didABC()"
```

If you do not want class A to be abstract, you can also do this

```
public class A
{
    public void doABC() { didABC(); }
    public void didABC() { System.out.println("A::didABC()"); }
}
```

Now you can also do this

```
A a = new A();
a.doABC(); // Prints "A::didABC()"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What you are trying to do cannot be achieved using inheritance. A parent will and should never know about what are the subclasses.
2. You can try to use Composition instead of inheritance. You can read about Composition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

A quick and dirty implementation of what you want:

```
interface DoAbc {
  public void doAbc();
}

class B implements DoAbc {
  public void doAbc() {
    //B's implementation
  }
}

class C implements DoAbc {
  public void doAbc() {
    //C's implementation
  }
}

class A implements DoAbc {
  DoAbc b,c;
  A(DoAbc b, DoAbc c) {
    this.b=b;
    this.c=c;
  }
  public void doAbc() {
  //A's implementation
    b.doAbc();
    c.doAbc();
  }
}
```

To any design pattern nazi's out there, I know its not a proper implementation of composite design pattern. Its just a quick and dirty implementation for what he wanted to achieve in the question.